# OrientDB with Spring polymorphism

Tags: java, spring, orientdb

I am trying the following thing in **Java with OrientDB** with Spring using spring-data-gremlin (which uses **gremlin API**).

```
class Audit extends BaseEntity{

 @oneToMany
 private BaseEntity auditOn;
}

Class Taxonomy extends BaseEntity {

}

Class BaseEntity {
}
```

Now I am trying to create a link between Audit via auditOn to Taxonomy and receiving the following exception in `Orient DB 2.2.3` where it is working fine in `Orient DB 2.2.2.`

```
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OValidationException: The field 'auditOn.in' has been declared as LINK of type 'BaseEntity' but the value is the document #154:1 of class 'Taxonomy'
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.validateLink(ODocument.java:484)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.validateField(ODocument.java:275)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.validate(ODocument.java:1953)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2259)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:118)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1727)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1718)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:76)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.embedded.OEmbeddedRidBag.serialize(OEmbeddedRidBag.java:371)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.ORidBag.toStream(ORidBag.java:274)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.writeSingleValue(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:581)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.serialize(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:261)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinary.toStream(ORecordSerializerBinary.java:105)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.toStream(ODocument.java:2100)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.toStream(ODocument.java:695)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.commitEntry(OStorageRemote.java:1998)
    ... 106 more
```

Comment: Hi, could you post a complete code to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Hi, The problem is with the API I am using, spring-data-gremlin which is not setting the superclass in the schema definition in ODB. Now I figured it out. Once I have overridden the code to do so, it all just worked fine.
Thanks a ton